# How to not display all the local calendars

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

Hello and thanks for the help,

What i want to do is create an app that will display several calendars with different tasks for example:

I have one calendar for my dog for when he will take a shower or go to the vet. 
One for my bird that also has when he will take a shower and go to the vet.
One for me, cause i need shower and go to the vet too! haha
something like that.

So i have been following this tutorial:
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-event-kit-programming-tutorial/

And my goal is when i press the bird profile and press the shower button only the birdShower calendar is shown and when i press the doctor only the birdDoctor calendar is shown.
And when i press the dog or my profile the same happens.

But what is happening now is that all local calendars are been displayed and i don't want that.

I am very bad at programming and i am just starting and i have been trying to fix this for days but i just failed. So my question is  how can i access and display the calendars i want for each profile menu (bath or doctor) without the other profiles or menus.. knowing about each other?

And how can i automatically set a new calendar for the user?
for example if he creates a new profile named Goku and than he presses the button BATH is it possible to create a calendar called GokuBaths automatically?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code for getting calender list.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if (granted)
             {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                     NSArray *cals = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType: EKEntityTypeEvent];
                     NSLog(@"Cals: %@",cals);
                 });
             }
             else
             {
                 //Error
             }
         }];
```